# Rspec rake task gem no longer importing

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

Pulling my hair out on this. I'm running some rspec specs through rake using rspec's rake task. Its been working fine until I started getting this error message:

```
rake aborted!  
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task
```

Here is the results of `gem list | grep rspec`

```
rspec (3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.1.7)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
rspec-support (3.1.2)
```

and here is the line I'm using to include the rake task in my Rakefile

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
```

I uninstalled all rspec gems and re-installed. Same error. As I mentioned I've been running these tests for a few months now without issue. There have been no changes to the environment and it runs in a VM so I can ensure it wasn't a coworker. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I double checked my `Gemfile.lock` file all the gem versions are matching with the one in the upstream repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I recommend running your specs through the `rspec` command.  It's far more flexible than running specs through `rake` and has less overhead.  Running the specs through `rake` is still useful as part of a build pipeline (the kind of thing `rake` is good at).

You haven't provided sufficient information to definitely answer your question, but I can provide some suggestions:

- Are you running `rake` via `bundle exec rake`?  Bundler is designed to manage the load path at runtime after it installs your gems, and should ensure that the installed `rspec-core/lib` is on your load path.
- You can add `puts $LOAD_PATH.join("\n")` to the top of your `Rakefile` to see what the load path is.  Is `rspec-core` in the list anywhere?  (I suspect it's not).  If it's not, then `require 'rspec/core/rake_task'` is not going to work unless `rspec-core` is installed as a system gem. Use `gem which rspec-core` to see if it's installed that way.

Comment: `bundle exec rake` works. I find it odd its worked for so long and without any changes to the system/env/gems/ect... it stopped working. Thank you, I was losing hair over this.